# gitlab - Fetch Dockerfile from script

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

We're using GITLAB CI/CD for deployment. This is the publish stage , Dockerfile is used here. If you check the script , I've integrated one environment variable(line no:10) , because we're using two jobs for publish itself like developer and stage. For that stage , I shown to you.

```
docker_build_stage:
    stage: Publish
    image: docker:19.03.11
    services:
        - docker:19.03.11-dind   
    variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    script: 
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
        - docker build --build-arg environment_name=stage  -t $IMAGE_TAG .
        - docker push $IMAGE_TAG   
    only:
        - /^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i
        - stage
```

This is the docker file , we're using.

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-11 AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/provider-service-*.jar /app/provider-service.jar
ENV PORT 8092
ENV env_var_name=$environment_name
EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active="$env_var_name,"-jar","/app/provider-service.jar"]
```

In the dockerfile , at last line(line no:12) , we add environment variable(line no:10), before ,the variable should be

> active=stage"

Because , we're maintaining respective branch as per the environment. Now, we merged developer and stage environment into single script. We are facing some fetching issue. Pipeline was successful but it doesn't fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely understand what is the issue you are mentioning, but I see you are missing ARG instruction in Dockerfile which is required to define the build-arg that you are passing if you want to use it in the build stage, in this case this arg "$environment_name"

You might change it like this

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-11 AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
FROM openjdk:11
ARG environment_name
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/provider-service-*.jar /app/provider-service.jar
ENV PORT 8092
ENV env_var_name=$environment_name
EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active="$env_var_name,"-jar","/app/provider-service.jar"]
```

Comment: I'm trying to say that , the variable name which is in script for the docker, can't fetching the variable properly. Can you check the Dockerfile, Which I've sent. There I mentioned(line no:10) the env variable is it ok? or else I want to go with your dockerfile, which you have sent

Comment: Yes you are missing ARG instruction so it is not able to use "environment_name" this arg which you are passing in build-arg to build command. You can try with the dockerfile which I shared

Comment: I'd updated the before comment. Please check

Comment: I've also updated it, to access that "environment_name", you need to define it in ARG instruction

Comment: Okay I'll try with your dockerfile and let you know

Comment: It is not woking properly. Pipeline has passed  , but there has a crash on kubernetes